# ASP DropDownList not working for jquery mobile (Android Browser)

Tags: android, asp.net, browser, jquery-mobile, drop-down-menu

anyone using **Andriod browsers** to try out **jquery mobile apps?**

i am using a ASP **dropdownlist** in jquery mobile. Viewing it in **safari** (iphone,itouch,ipad) is not a problem but **Andriod default browser** just **cant have the list "dropped down"** for some reasons.

Any experts out there who can advice me on what to do?

---

ok guys i have found the solution to it.

add **data-native-menu="false"** attribute to the asp:dropdownlist

it will look like this :

asp:DropDownList ID="ddltrade" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True"
data-icon="search" **data-native-menu="false"**

Comment: can you post the html that is generated?

Comment: you can view the main page by pressing the "demo" button.at the main page, you will be able to see the "troubled" Select choice dropdownlist..thanks!

Comment: hey shanabus you can view my website @ www.easyapps.sg/ulp/mobile using your andriod phone browser. Thanks! –

Comment: I'm glad you found the solution. The way Stack Overflow works, you would add more value if you could post your solution as an answer and mark it so.  Many readers to not expect to find the answer as an update to the solution.  Or if you like, I'll post the answer and grab the points :)